# Can't make this work: Accessing files outside site root as per SO entry

Tags: php, apache

I am trying to learn how to access files outside of the site root folder. I found an interesting post on SO [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8676144/reading-image-from-outside-public-html-with-php) that provided some very simple code:

"if you want to provide access to a file outside of the document root, you'll have to do it via a script. The simplest method is to have:

image.php:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
readfile('/path/to/picture/outside/doc/root/file.jpg');
?> //original post was missing this closing tag
```

and in your html:

```
<img src="image.php">
```

"

I also read [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10530001/how-to-securely-store-files-on-a-server/10530250#10530250) anout the proper path on a cPanel server running Apache (I am running Apache 2.0) which was listed as:

```
/var/www/username
```

And I tried all that, amending the first code above with the correct path and my own account username. I upload the `image.php` file and the page that calls it and when I test the page, I get nada. A look at the source code and also examine the element in Firebug and it shows what one might expect:

```
<img src="image.php" />
```

So...what am I missing here? The original question had this solution checked as a valid answer.

I have seen mentions of `mod_rewrite` all day (I have been at this for the entire day) and am not certain if that is valid here or not.

Many thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: The original post was probably intentionally omitting the closing tag.

Comment: What does `image.php` show when you call it? For the record btw, this *exact* implementation does not add any security, it just creates additional overhead by calling PHP. Do you have a specific case why you want to do this (like a user authentication) instead of having the image in the web dir?

Comment: @Pekka I want to keep the contents of the images folder available to users but not available to anyone typing the file URL into a browser. I have researched .htaccess all day with no luck, and I have also seen recommendations to store files outside the site root to keep them from being available through a browser direct URL.

Comment: You can't just assume the vhost path from another post. You need to look at `phpinfo()` or ask your provider for help. Each setup is different. Make sure the absolute path is correct. Enable `error_reporting`.

Comment: @Pekka when I call image.php as a file in the browser, a .jpg is displayed with a warning: `The image"http://www.website.com/image.php" cannot be displayed because it contains errors.`

Comment: Remove the `header()` line and you'll see PHP errors

Comment: @Pekka I get an enormous blob of gibberish.

Comment: Then it might be the additional `?` at the end in `?>?`

Comment: @Pekka My apologies, that extra `?` is not in the code of my file, that was a typo on my part.

Comment: Can you get rid of the closing `?>` altogether? Maybe there's white space that is interfering with the JPG

Comment: @Pekka I tried that also. No different

Comment: You need to find out about the errors. Download the URL with `wget` or `curl` (commandline) and compare against the original JPEG, using `diff` etc. It's typically leading garbage (PHP notices, whitespace), seldomly truncation or trailing garbage, if the image can't be displayed in the browser.

Comment: Can you copypaste the first 30 characters of gibberish?

Comment: @Pekka here are thei first 40... `ÿØÿàJFIFddÿìDucky<ÿâXICC_PROFILE`

Comment: Strange, that looks okay. Not sure what is going on here... does the image work if you copy it into the web root directly and call it from there?

Comment: @Pekka oddly enough, I get the same white screen, no image, greyed out code in Firebug...

Comment: Then the image itself may be broken. Or just white :)

Comment: @Pekka, but it isn't, I can view it on my local machine.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25104/discussion-between-wordman-and-pekka-)

Answer (score 0):

In Web Host Manager (WHM) you need to enable the PHP open_basedir Tweak for the each user you want to allow access outside of its root.

If you are using cPanel on a linux environment, WHM should be available by going to http://yourdomain.com/whm

Refer to http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/11_36/WHMDocs/WebHome

Comment: This sounds like Windows/IIS advice? He seems to be on a Linux box

Comment: using WHM on linux with Cpanel... no Windows environment. Refer to http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/11_36/WHMDocs/WebHome